# Animating view visibility with both fade in and zoom in

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view

I have a RelativeLayout whose width and height are as large as the app window, and its visibility is initially set to View.GONE.

I'd like to show this view when a button is clicked. I'd like fade in and zoom in to be applied simultaneously. The fade in part is easily done using ViewPropertyAnimator. My problem is that I'm clueless as to how the view can be made to appear as if it is expanding to the full size from a smaller size as it fades in.

Is there any built in animation for this? I've done a bit of searching but haven't found anything. Maybe I'm not using the right search keywords or something. Could anybody please help?

Comment: ViewPropertyAnimator.scale*() ?

Comment: I found that the zoom in bit can be done using ScaleAnimation. Now, the problem is using ViewPropertyAnimator with it. Will they run in parallel?

Comment: have you read this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html ?

Comment: Yes, I have. It is not suitable for what I want.

Comment: scale*() methods are not suitable?  why?

Comment: That's because unlike ScaleAnimation, ViewPropertyAnimator.scale() does not accept initial scale factor from which to start scaling to the full size.

Comment: @pskink Please see my answer. I hope this helps you, myself and future visitors.

Comment: @DavidHeisnam: the fact that scale*() does not accept a start value is not a problem. Check out my answer to know how to solve it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- Concatenate the methods of `ViewPropertyAnimator`,

so the animations will run in parallel. `AnimationSet` is part of an old api and you should prefer view property animations over it. If you want to use that technique (which is a bit longer to write and less optmized), you can opt for `AnimatorSet` (Animat-**or** ...).

Here is a code snippet that solves your problem with view property animations:

```
view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
view.setAlpha(0.f);
view.setScaleX(0.f);
view.setScaleY(0.f);
view.animate()
    .alpha(1.f)
    .scaleX(1.f).scaleY(1.f)
    .setDuration(300)
    .start();
```

A good tutorial on view property animations is [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.de/2011/05/introducing-viewpropertyanimator.html).

Comment: AnimationSet is working exactly as desired, but I think it's better to follow your suggestion, based on what the tutorial says. Thanks a lot, Gil.

Comment: Well the old api has the advantage to be back compatible to everything, but other than that I would always use the 11+ api (ObjectAnimator, ValueAnimator, ViewPropertyAnimator, AnimatorSet...). For example, one drawback of the old api, is that Views are not really animated (only the rendered graphics are animated). You can end up having the rendering of the View somewhere on screen but the View will be responsive to clicks in another region of screen. Kind of weird. The new api does not have this problem: the entire View is moved/scaled/animated post layout

Comment: I don't care about pre-ICS devices anymore. So I prefer only the newest possible APIs.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using an AnimationSet, adding AlphaAnimation and ScaleAnimation.

```
AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(true);
animation.addAnimation(new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0F));
animation.addAnimation(new ScaleAnimation(0.8f, 1, 0.8f, 1)); // Change args as desired
animation.setDuration(300);
mView.startAnimation(animation);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do sliding left and right animation of view by this respectively.

```
TranslateAnimation animate = new TranslateAnimation(0,-view.getWidth(), 0, 0);
animate.setDuration(time);
view.startAnimation(animate);
TranslateAnimation anim = new TranslateAnimation(-400f, 0f,0f,0f);
anim.setDuration(time);
view.startAnimation(anim );
```